# How to import module into Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, spotify

The Spotify Api docs want me to implement a module into Android Studio. But I don't find the screen they are refering to. Can anybody help me find this screen:) https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/android/quick-start/

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tn3Jk.png)

Comment: Doc clearly says import jar/.aar and your screenshot has the same selected . Whats your question here ? Create a project go to `File->new->import module`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add android library as ".aar" file, you can find adding module option in Android Studio toolbar.

[image]